# Can I make text transparent in konsole?

Tags: terminal, konsole

I can make the background transparent, but can I adjust the transparency of the actual text? Do any other terminals support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use KDE? KDE allows to adjust transparency for given window, being it konsole or not. Click the program icon in the top <strike>right</strike> left corner. I cannot guide you too strictly from there because I use non-English translation. Look for something like "additional window settings".

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running full KDE you can use [Compton](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compton) with this rule in your `.conf` file:

```
opacity-rule = [ "95:class_g = 'konsole'" ];
```

Where `95` is your opacy percentage.